# Facebook news feed is not showing most of my current liked pages updates and posts

Tags: facebook

I'm not getting updated posts from most--but not all- of my liked pages in my news-feed in Facebook like local news channels, Fox News, local library page, etc.

This has happened more often in the last few weeks.

I tried hovering over the "liked" button on these pages and it does show that "show in news feed" is checked.

I've tried this from [How do I control what I see in my news feed?](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=218728138156311):

> #### Unhide stories from a person, Page, group, event or app
>
> 1. From your home page, hover over **news feed** in the left sidebar menu.
> 2. Click the pencil icon that appears to the left.
> 3. A list of people, apps, Pages, and groups you’ve hidden or unsubscribed
>    from will appear in a pop-up box. Click the **X** next to each one you'd like to remove from this list. Removing someone or something from your list of hidden stories means those stories can appear in your news feed again.
> 4. Click **Save**.

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Changes in the stories hidden/show setting in the Facebook feeds could take a while to make the changes being reflected.

I assume that it could take no more than 24 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has recently re-weighted the feed so posts from your facebook "friends" receive greater priority than posts from the Pages that you have liked. One reason they have done this is so they can charge the Pages money to make sure their posts get ranked higher in the feed and people will be more likely to see them, they also market this to the users saying they will see more news from their friends rather than corporations.

There is a separate feed for just viewing posts from the Pages you have liked. It is called the "**Pages feed**", you can view it here: https://facebook.com/feed/pages

You could bookmark that feed and add the bookmark to your bookmarks bar at the top of your browser for easy access.